# Call function from another window

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, methods, call

I have a problem with call of one MainWindow function from another windows.

I have 4 windows: MainWindow, Window1, Window2 and Window3. MainWindow open Window1, Window1 open window2 and Window2 open Window3. I want to call MainWindow function from Window1 and Window3. I can call this function from Window1 but i don't know how to do this from Window3.

Code: call MainWindow function from Window1:

MainWindow:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Window1 w1 = new Window1();
     w1.Owner = this;
     w1.ShowDialog();
}
```

Window1:

```
public void button_cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{         
    var myObject = this.Owner as MainWindow;
    myObject.ruLanguage();
}
```

ruLanguage(); - functon to call from MainWindow

Comment: Pass it as a ctor parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, you can access the main window through the [`Application.MainWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow.aspx) property.

```
public void button_cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{         
    var myObject = Application.MainWindow as MainWindow;
    myObject.ruLanguage();
}
```

You could also define properties on your windows, so you could use them like that:

```
public MainWindow AppMainWindow { get; set; }

private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Window1 w1 = new Window1();
     w1.Owner = this;
     w1.AppMainWindow = this;
     w1.ShowDialog();
}
```

And then pass the value of `AppMainWindow` around.

As a side note, you may want to reconsider your design. Learn about the MVVM pattern, it's the better way to use WPF.